# Не выполняется контракт

Tags: c#

Всем добрый вечер. У меня возникла следующая проблема - пытаюсь воспользоваться появившимися в C# 4 контрактами для проверки кода, но они почему-то не срабатывают. 
У меня есть следующий код:

```
    public static  string Type<T>(T some)
    {
        /* было бы очень здорово, если бы следующая  строка выполнялась, чего она, однако,     не делает */
        Contract.Requires(some != null); 
        return some.GetType().ToString(); 
    }
```

Работаю в Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. Решарпер при этом любезно подсвечивает код серым цветом, сообщая, что Compiler will not generate method invocation because the method is conditional, or it's partial method wihout implementation. 
Вероятно, я что-то упустил, но вот что?

Comment: Загляните в свойства проекта, может, вы забыли включить проверку контрактов?

Comment: может, и забыл. но вот только почему-то вкладки Code Contracts у меня нет((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Загляните в свойства проекта, может, вы забыли включить проверку контрактов? Без неё не взлетит :)

Если этой вкладки нет, вам сюда:

[I just installed Visual Studio 2010, now how do I get Code Contracts?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/i-just-installed-visual-studio-2010-now-how-do-i-get-code-contracts-melitta-andersen)

Comment: большое спасибо, помогло))

Comment: @DreamChild: пожалуйста!